# C# - track WM_LBUTTONDOWN outside the form

Tags: c#

I want to get when the left mouse is clicked, outside of the form. I've found this can be done with WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but I have been searching for hours and yet haven't found out how to get it to work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: WM_LBUTTONDOWN is only posted to the form under the cursor when the button is clicked - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607.aspx

Comment: I think you need a global hook - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: when I run it it crashes, gives an error instantly...
only version one works, I'll check the source out

Comment: Great diagnostic, you'll get lots of help with that one.  SetWindowsHookEx for WH_MOUSe_LL has been done thousands of times before at this site.  Use the Search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you need a global hook.  The resource that Blorgbeard posted does indeed work, with a few modifications.
When the calls to 'SetWindowsHookEx' are made in HookManager.Callbacks.cs change the argument:

```
Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0])
// to this:
IntPtr.Zero
```

And it will suddenly start working.  Come to think of it, I also changed the target platform from 2.0 to 4.0 as well.  You might need to do that too.  Anyway, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Global hook is somehow overheaded, you could call `SetCapture` to capture the mouse event.